# How to read from file in Java with confirm attributes

Tags: java, attributes, confirm, reader, writer

Is it possible to determine the properties of an object after it is read from a file in Java?

Suppose I write a list of students (name, age, grades,...) into the file "student.txt".
When I read to the file "student.txt" is there any way I can confirm the attributes (name, age, score, ...)?

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.  I think you will want to edit your tags on the question. (confirm tag mentions JavaScript but not Java. Note I don't know the confirm function).

Comment: What do you mean with "confirm"?

Comment: sr, i am new
i want to said here , object-oriented java (OOP)

Comment: tag "confirm" maybe I don't understand English very well, but I mean:
EG: I save a list of students in a file "student.txt" with class Student and attributes : - String name,-String age,-String GPA,...
After saving I want to extract backwards from the file to the program, can I "confirm" in the file "Student.txt" the attributes: String name, age, GPA?
sout("Name:"+getName); such as.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose we have serialization and deserialization in java
When you serialize a java object(in your case a list of user objects) in a file say x
So when you deserialize by reading from file x , it will transform the file to list of user objects.
At time of deserialization it will check that is the type properties of the user class(name, age, grades,...) is same as defined in class or not
While deserialization you can add logic to check if property present or not